# Is there a number $n$, such that there are $22$ groups of order $n$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, computational-complexity

Denot : $N(n)$ : the number of groupfs of order $n$ ?

> Is there a number $n$ with $N(n)=22$ ?

Checking the first about $2000$ numbers, I noticed that there is no $n\in [1,2000]$ with $N(n)=22$. Does such an $n$ exist ? And if no, why ?

Generalization : Given a number $k$, can we determine whether there is a $n$ with $N(n)=k$ in a reasonable time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Maple, there are a number of values of $n < 50000$ for which $N(n) = 22$:

```
> with( GroupTheory ):
> select( n -> NumGroups( n ) = 22, [seq]( 1 .. 50000 ) );

        [6321, 9075, 9765, 18135, 18669, 19215, 27075, 31017, 31605, 35685, 40053, 45045, 46431, 47565, 49539]
```

There is a conjecture that $N$ is surjective, but to my knowledge, there is little progress on this problem.

Comment: Thank you! Did you find a solution of $N(n)=n$ ? And how can I prove that $N(n)\le\phi(n)$ for squarefree $n>1$ ?

Comment: @Peter I did check for $N(n) = n$ but, for the known values with $2 < n < 50000$, there were none.

Comment: This is Conjecture 8.1 in https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/gnu.pdf   

but they say it was conjectured even earlier, in stronger forms.


They also show surjectivity for many small values and say that Keith Dennis has checked for all $k$ up to $10000000$.